# SQL multiple insert select in one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new in SQL and I'm trying to put values in my table that has two foreign keys.

```
CREATE TABLE ROOM 
(
  ROOM_NAME VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) 
, PATIENT_ID NUMBER 
, DOC_NAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE USERS 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  NEXT 1048576 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL;

ALTER TABLE ROOM
ADD CONSTRAINT DOC_ROOM FOREIGN KEY (DOC_NAME)
REFERENCES DOCTOR(DOC_NAME) ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE ROOM
ADD CONSTRAINT PATIENT_ROOM FOREIGN KEY (PATIENT_ID)
REFERENCES RECORD(ID) ENABLE;
```

Created using the left panel in **SQL Developer**. As you can see I have two foreign keys. I have no idea how to add values to the columns `Patient_ID` and `Doc_Name`.

So far what I did was just inserting one by one into the table, but that resulted in having three different rows.

**What I got:**

```
   ROOM_NAME    | PATIENT_ID | DOC_NAME
---------------------------------------
 Emergency Room |    NULL    |   NULL
       NULL     |      1     |   NULL
       NULL     |    NULL    | Dr. John
```

**What I want to get:**

```
   ROOM_NAME    | PATIENT_ID | DOC_NAME
---------------------------------------
Emergency Room  |       1    | Dr. John
```

Comment: Please show us your `insert` statement.

Answer (score 0):

`insert` will always create a new row (unless some constraint is violated).

To insert a row with all values at once, use this:

```
insert into room 
   (ROOM_NAME, PATIENT_ID, DOC_NAME)
values 
   ('Emergency Room', 1, 'Dr. John');
```

If you want to change an already existing row, you need to use the [`UPDATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10008.htm#SQLRF01708) statement, e.g:

```
update room
   set doc_name = 'Dr. House'
where room_name = 'Emergency Room'
  and patient_id = 1;
```

---

Your `room` table is missing a primary key, you should add one that uniquely identifies rows in this table.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind. Saw the answer from another question.

```
insert into room values ('EmergencyRoom', (Select id from record where id = 1), (select doc_name from DOCTOR where doc_name = 'Dr. John'))
```

Comment: You might as well just do :- INSERT INTO ROOM VALUES ('EmergencyRoom', 1, 'Dr. John')